# How can I evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ \sqrt{x} (x+1)}{x^4+1} dx $ by using Residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

How can I evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} (x+1)}{x^4+1} dx$$ by using Residue theorem.

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: Try the contour with branch cut like : https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-37a34d148b35697f7c846a8363e2382d.webp

Comment: sub $x=t^2$ then the upper half plane contour should work.

Answer (score 2):

See the link [Closed form for $ \int_0^\infty {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^m}}}dx }$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx) for integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^b}dx =\frac\pi {b\sin\frac{\pi a}b}$. Then,

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x} (x+1)}{x^4+1} dx
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{5/2-1}}{x^4+1} dx +\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{3/2-1}}{x^4+1} dx \\
&= \frac\pi{4\sin\frac{5\pi}8 }+ \frac\pi{4\sin\frac{3\pi}8}=\frac\pi4 \frac{ \sin\frac{5\pi}8 +\sin\frac{3\pi}8}{\sin\frac{5\pi}8 \sin\frac{3\pi}8}\\
 &=\frac\pi4 \frac{ 2\cos\frac{\pi}8}{\cos^2\frac{\pi}8}=\frac\pi{2\cos\frac\pi8}
\end{align}

Comment: +1 Great answer, but in the last line, there's no need to simplify the denominator into $1 + \cos \frac{\pi}{4}$ since $\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{8}$ works fine as well.

Comment: @Toby Mak - right, didn’t realize it. Will make a change. Thank

Answer (score 0):

We seek to compute using contour integration the integral

$$J = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x} (x+1)}{x^4+1} \; dx$$

We work with

$$f(z) = \frac{\exp(\mathrm{Log}(z)/2) (z+1)}{z^4+1}$$

where $\mathrm{Log}(z)$ is the branch  with argument in $[0,2\pi).$ We
use a keyhole contour wih radius $R$ and the slot on the positive real
axis.  Let $\Gamma_0$  be the  segment  on the  real axis  up to  $R$,
$\Gamma_1$ the big circle of  radius $R$, $\Gamma_2$ the segment below
the real  axis coming  in from  $R$ and  finally $\Gamma_3$  the small
circle of radius $\epsilon$ enclosing the origin. We then have with

$$\rho_k =  \exp(\pi i/4+\pi i k/2)$$

that

$$\left(\int_{\Gamma_0}
+ \int_{\Gamma_1}+ \int_{\Gamma_2}+ \int_{\Gamma_3}\right) f(z) \; dz
= 2\pi i \times 
\sum_{k=0}^3 \mathrm{Res}_{z=\rho_k} f(z).$$

The poles are all simple and we get for the residues

$$\frac{\exp(\mathrm{Log}(\rho_k)/2) (\rho_k+1)}{4\rho_k^3}
= -\frac{\exp(\mathrm{Log}(\rho_k)/2) \rho_k (\rho_k+1)}{4}
\\ = -\frac{\exp(\pi i/8 + \pi i k/4 + \pi i/2 + \pi i k)}{4}
- \frac{\exp(\pi i/8 + \pi i k/4 + \pi i/4 + \pi i k/2)}{4}
\\ = - \frac{\exp(5\pi i/8) \exp(5\pi i k/4)}{4}
 - \frac{\exp(3\pi i/8) \exp(3\pi i k/4)}{4}.$$

Summing over $k$ we find

$$-\frac{1}{4} \exp(5\pi i/8) \sum_{k=0}^3 \exp(5\pi i k/4) 
= -\frac{1}{4} \exp(5\pi i/8) \frac{2}{1-\exp(5\pi i/4)}$$

and

$$-\frac{1}{4} \exp(3\pi i/8) \sum_{k=0}^3 \exp(3\pi i k/4) 
= -\frac{1}{4} \exp(3\pi i/8) \frac{2}{1-\exp(3\pi i/4)}.$$

Now observe that in the limit for $\Gamma_0$ and $\Gamma_2$

$$\int_{\Gamma_0} f(z) \; dz = J$$

and

$$\int_{\Gamma_2} f(z) \; dz =
\int_{\infty}^0 \exp(\pi i) \frac{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}{x^4+1} \; dx
= \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x}(x+1)}{x^4+1} \; dx = J.$$

For  the large  circle of  radius $R$  we have  by the  ML-estimate on
$\Gamma_1$   the   bound   $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}   2\pi   R\times
\frac{\sqrt{R} (R+1)}{R^4-1}  = 0,$  so this  vanishes. For  the small
circle    $\Gamma_3$     of      radius     $\epsilon$     we     find
$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow      0}      2\pi      \epsilon      \times
\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}(1+\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon^4}  = 0,$  and this  too
vanishes.

The conclusion is that
$$J = \frac{1}{2} \times 2\pi i
\left(-\frac{1}{2}  \frac{\exp(5\pi i/8)}{1-\exp(5\pi i/4)}
-\frac{1}{2} \frac{\exp(3\pi i/8) }{1-\exp(3\pi i/4)}\right)
\\ = -\frac{\pi i}{2} 
\left(\frac{1}{\exp(-5\pi i/8)-\exp(5\pi i/8)} +
\frac{1}{\exp(-3\pi i/8)-\exp(3\pi i/8)}\right)
\\ = \frac{\pi i}{4i} 
\left(\frac{2i}{-\exp(-5\pi i/8)+\exp(5\pi i/8)} +
\frac{2i}{-\exp(-3\pi i/8)+\exp(3\pi i/8)}\right).$$

This at last yields the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\sin(3\pi/8)} +
\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\sin(5\pi/8)}.}$$

This admits further simplification as the two arguments to the sine 
function are symmetric about $\pi/2$ so we get

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\sin(3\pi/8)}.}$$